# fread() in R (data.table) returns blanks for " "

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am new to R programming. I have been using the data.table package, specifically fread, to import a file from a website. The file is type csv. The file has a lot of junk in it. What is causing an issue for me are the fields with " ". I've tried a variety of ways to coax the " " to NA, but haven't had luck. I did find this relevant posting:

[Blank space not recognised as NA in fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019041/blank-space-not-recognised-as-na-in-fread)

I modified `fread` to say:

`data6<-fread("https://data.colorado.gov/resource/8jg4-bud5.csv", na.strings = c("", "NA"))` and did see a lot of improvement with "".

Please help me address the issue in the file with " " or provide a workaround to change this to NA. I've tried a host of ways with no luck.

(I process the NA's later in the data cleansing phase).

You can download the file and modify it with -  `data6<-fread("https://data.colorado.gov/resource/8jg4-bud5.csv", na.strings = c("", "NA"))`.

Comment: At first glance, adding a `" "` to your `na.strings` seems to be filling all values with NA that were otherwise empty. Does that provide intended behavior?

Comment: I resolved the issue with: S<-" ", v<-which(data6[]==S, arr.ind=TRUE), data6[v]<-0

Comment: caw5cv, the option of adding " " to na.strings doesn't work unfortunately. Thanks for your input!